# Nginx permanent redirect to different url for certain subdirectory

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have 2 Nginx servers serving static files from 2 different subdomains of an unknown parent domain, let's say `<env>.foo.<domain>.com` and `<env>.bar.<domain>.com`.

I want to configure the nginx server for `<env>.foo.<domain>.com` so that if the url has the subdirectory `cat` or `dog` I want to redirect to `<env>.bar.<domain>.com/<subdirectory>/<rest of url>`.

E.g.

```
http://dev.foo.mydomain1.com/cat/22 -> http://dev.bar.mydomain1.com/cat/22
http://dev.foo.mydomain1.com/dog/22 -> http://dev.bar.mydomain2.com/dog/22
http://dev.foo.mydomain2.com/dog/22 -> http://dev.bar.mydomain2.com/dog/22
http://dev.foo.mydomain1.com/bird/22 -> [no redirect]
```

The `<env>` and `<domain>` portions of the domain are dynamic depending to the environment to which the servers are deployed, but are common between the 2 nginx boxes.

I imagine it being something like:

```
server {
  location ??? /(cat|dog) {
    return 301 $scheme://???/$1$is_args$query_string;
  }
}
```

But my nginx skills are not quite there...

Comment: `dev.foo.mydomain2.com` and `dev.foo.mydomain1.com` are handled on same nginx or different nginx? also do these listen in same server blocks or different server blocks?

Comment: same nginx, but deployed to different environments. E.g. staging.foo.domain1.com, demo.foo.domain2.com

Comment: `foo` and `bar` subdomains are on entirely separate nginx boxes

Answer (score 3):

```
rewrite ^/oldlocation$ http://www.newdomain.com/newlocation permanent;
```

Refer [digital oceans's article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx) on "How To Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Nginx" for further details.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is below

```
http {

map $http_host $host_to_send_to {
  default $http_host;
  dev.foo.mydomain1.com    dev.bar.mydomain1.com;
  dev.foo.mydomain2.com    dev.bar.mydomain2.com;
}

server {
  server_name dev.foo.mydomain1.com;
  location /(cat|dog) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host_to_send_to$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
  }
}
}
```

You will need to add it to each server block which needs to handle the redirect.

**Edit-1: Dynamic host name handling**

You can handling host names dynamically also user re patterns and groups

```
map $hostsname $host_to_send_to {
  default $http_host;
  ~(.*).foo.mydomain1.com    $1.bar.mydomain1.com;
  ~(.*).foo.mydomain2.com    $1.bar.mydomain2.com;
}
```

Comment: what if I don't know what the `server_name` is as the same config is deployment to multiple environments? I.e. it should work regardless of the domain and dynamically use the domain parts from the request, except for the `foo`/`bar` parts which are substituted

Comment: @harryg, posted solution for that also